# Is there any way to add some query param in middleware and pass it to server router (next js)

Tags: javascript, next.js, middleware

Next.js v12.2.5

Trying something like URL object as here https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#with-url-object to add query param. It's not working.

Is there any way to add query param inside middleware which can be used inside `useRouter()` on the server side?

```
// middleware.ts (conceptual example)
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.rewrite({
    pathname: '/',
    query: { requiredParam: 'something' }, // add requiredParam inside middleware
  });
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/'],
};
```

Answer (score -2):

It's possible to do so, it's just that `NextResponse.rewrite` expects a different format than the object used in `next/link`.

You can pass a `URL` object in the following format to make it work.

```js
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(`/?requiredParam=something`, request.url));;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I had to use this approach: `request.nextUrl.searchParams.set('invalidUuid', 'true'); return NextResponse.rewrite(url);`